# Even the examples don't get executed in Tomcat 4.0 server

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to run a jsp file on Tomcat 4.0. This file runs properly on Windows XP, where i use the same set of softwares.

Now I try to run the file on Windows 8 , but even the sample examples don't run 
I get this error:
 The requested resource (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Tomcat 4.0\work\Standalone\localhost\examples\jsp\jsptoserv\jsptoservlet$jsp.java (The system cannot find the path specified)) is not available.

I've set the JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, CATALINA_HOME .
I've copied the web.xml file from the ROOT folder. 
And I placed my jsp files in the web apps folder.
When I type localhost:8080/ it says the tomcat has been setup successfully.

Is there anything extra that I must do while working on Windows8 when compared to Windows XP?

Comment: Support for Tomcat 4.0.x ended about 10 years ago. You *really* need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Just some wild guess:
I don't know about Windows 8, but under Windows 7 you're out of luck when installing tomcat in `C:\Program Files(x86)`. Since the `temp` and `work`directory also reside there the tomcat process has to write somwhere under this path when compiling jsp and in this location under Windows 7 UAC kicks in and requires elevated privileges for the process.

It is not sufficient to run tomcat with an administrative account, you either have to turn off UAC (not recommended!!!) or install tomcat to a different location that is not considered a system-directory by the UAC (e.g. `C:\tomcat`).